# Batch different way to access array

Tags: batch-file, command-line

This is my script:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "memuc=d:\file.exe"

set array[0]=foo
set array[1]=bar

set x=0


:SymLoop
if defined array[!x!] (
    call "!memuc!" start -n !!array[%x%]!!

    set /A x=!x! + 1
    GOTO :SymLoop
)

endlocal
```

1. Why `array[!x!]` line cannot be replaced with with `!array[%x%]!`? I thought I have to use `!` when accesing `delayedExpansion` variables.
2. Why I have to use `%x%` instead `!x!`?. The same, I thought `!` should be necessary accesing `x` variable
3. Why I have to use two `!` here `!!array[%x%]!!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got the concept wrong.  The `!` means that the value of the variable will be *expanded* as late as possible.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "_var=stackoverflow"
set "_var=rules" & echo "%_var% !_var!"
```

This will print `"stackoverflow rules"` due to the fact of the delayed expansion.

Now to your questions:

**Addum 1.** The reason is the `if defined`.  If you would like to put there the actual variable you would use e.g. your `array[0]` that is the reason why you have `array[!x!]` and not `!array[%x%]!`.

**Addum 2.** You have to use `%x%` to have immediate expansion as you want to have `array[0]` and `array[1]`.  If you would write it as `!x!` then you would be searching, if written as `%array[!x!]%` for `array[!x!]`.

**Addum 3.** The double exclamation marks (`!!`) is there due to the fact that `call` introduces one more expansion.  So first you have immediate expansion of `%x%` then you have an expansion of `array[0]` and then expansion for the `call`.